# AngularJS data binding within another data binding

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I just stepped into the AngularJS world, and need a solution for the application I am working on.

So here is the definition of the module.

```
var samplesApp = angular.module('samples', []);

samplesApp.controller('samplesController', function ($scope) {
   var jsonObj=
      [
         {"ACTION":"UPDATE","ID":"22","ROUTE":"0015"},
         {"ACTION":"DELETE","ID":"20","ROUTE":"0015"},
         {"ACTION":"UPDATE","ID":"19","ROUTE":"0015"}
      ]
    $scope.records = jsonObj;

    var columnNames = [];
    for (var key in jsonObj[0]) {
        columnNames.push(key);
    }

    $scope.columnNames = columnNames;

});
```

The $scope JSON object is a part of the output of the real data that comes from database. and I need to put these data into a table dynamically

The html is like

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th data-ng-repeat="column in columnNames">{{column}}</th>
    </thead>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="record in records">
        <td data-ng-repeat="column in columnNames">{{ record.{{ column }} }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Because I have no idea what the column name is, so I made a process to get all the column names and push them into $scope.columnNames. and then bind it to the table header. There is no problem for this part. The issue is I don't know how to get the value coresponse to the specific column. I was trying to do it like this:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="column in columnNames">{{ record.{{ column }} }}</td>
```

But apparently it is not working.

Can someone give me some advice? really appreciate it.

Comment: Just an FYI, you have an array of `records` defined on your scope but are referencing `AllRecords` in your markup

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change it when I was extracting the code from my project, I have already updated the post. Thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using brackets, like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="record in AllRecords">
    <td data-ng-repeat="column in columnNames">{{ record[column] }}</td>
</tr>
```

The expressions inside `{{ }}` (moustaches?) are evaluated pretty narrowly to how regular javascript is evaluated.

Comment: Yes, that is it. really appreciate it, Mikke.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing with the record[column] operator is OK, but
you could try this other alternative. In this example, the semantics
of the code is a bit better, and you have less coupling (your rows just
depend on the data, not the variable used in the header):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="column in columnNames">{{column}}</th>
    </tr>

    <tr data-ng-repeat="record in records">
        <td data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in record">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the working example with your data: http://plnkr.co/edit/CskLQ2ZZlYIURdNPXiZt?p=preview

Here's the Angular docs for the [ngRepeat directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) (look for "key, value")

Comment: Thanks for the advice, GonchuB, I tried this, and it did give me all the records shows up there, but the value does not match the column name in the <th> very well. But I am 100% sure that this is a very nice solution for parsing the JSON object.

Comment: Glad I helped. Just to know, which part didn't work for you? The `<th data-ng-repeat="column in columnNames">`? Cause I took that one from your code xD

Comment: I'll put it this way, let say I use <td data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in record">{{key}}</td>. Notice that I changed "{{value}}" to "{{key}}", when it display, it is not showing the same name as the name on the <th> header. I have no idea how the mismatch happened.